# actionlib - SimpleActionServer - Accept new goal only on certain condition

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I couldn't come up with an easy way to do the following having a look at actionlib's source code and documentation:

If I'm right, SimpleActionServer's default policy is to cancel the active goal upon a new goal arrival. What I try to do is make the server only accept a new goal if the goal parameters meet certain condition.

For instance, supose that my goal have an integer parameter called "priority". I'd like a new goal to be accepted (hence preemping the active goal) by the server if the new arrived goal priority is bigger than the active's.

Is it possible to do this by only using SimpleActionServer's ExecuteCallback?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10287/actionlib---simpleactionserver---accept-new-goal-only-on-certain-condition/) by [Enric Galceran](https://answers.ros.org/users/703/enric-galceran/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-06-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you want more advanced goal behavior you should use the actionserver instead of the simpleactionserver see the actionlib documentation: http://www.ros.org/wiki/actionlib

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1